# EmptyStack exception related to Postfix Evaluation

Tags: java, exception

The program should accept input from user in the form of postfix expression and evaluate it. I need to use array and char for this program due to my assignment requirement. Now the problem is I'm getting EmptyStackException which I don't know why. I need to print the final result for the evaluation.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class StackPostfixEva {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] postfix = new char[10];
        System.out.println("Please enter postfix expression. "
                + "Enter '#' if you have finish entering postfix expression");
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            postfix[i] = key.next().charAt(0);
            if (postfix[i] == '#') {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The postfix expression are:");
        for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
            System.out.println(postfix[i]);
        }
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
        int result, ch1, ch2;
        for (i = 0; i <= postfix.length; i++) {
            if (postfix[i] >= '0' && postfix[i] <= '9') {
                st.push(postfix[i] - '0');
            } else {
                ch1 = st.pop();
                ch2 = st.pop();
                switch (postfix[i]) {
                case '+':
                    result = ch2 + ch1;
                    break;
                case '-':
                    result = ch2 - ch1;
                    break;
                case '*':
                    result = ch2 * ch1;
                    break;
                case '/':
                    result = ch2 / ch1;
                    break;
                case '%':
                    result = ch2 / ch1;
                    break;
                default:
                    result = 0;
                }
                st.push(result);
            }
        }
        result = st.pop();
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the messy work and thanks in advance for helping me. ^_^

Comment: You're getting an EmptyStackException because you're trying to pop an empty stack. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: `"Sorry for the messy work ..."` -- Don't apologize for the messy work -- fix it! Format your code so that others can read it. Why on earth would you want to make a difficult thing -- understanding someone else's code -- more difficult? I've done it for you now, but in the future, **you** should be doing this.

Comment: @shmosel But I did push the char before.

Comment: Obviously not. Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks mate. Thank you for the advice. I will practice writing my code properly. Thank you. ^_^

Comment: @shmosel Which mean the command st.push(postfix[i] - '0');  did not push the character into the stack? If it yes, how to push then? 
Sorry I'm total newbie in java.

Comment: `push()` will always push and `pop()` will pop if the stack is not empty. It's up to you to step through the code and figure out what sequence of steps is causing it to try to pop more items than have been pushed. We're not going to do it for you, especially considering you've omitted basic diagnostic information, like the stack trace and your test input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere you are checking for

```
if(st.isEmpty())
```

Also, why are you popping out two elements at once and not checking for empty stack ?

```
  else{  //execution if operator found
    ch1 = st.pop();
    ch2 = st.pop();
```

Obviously, if there is one element in the stack and if the next line execute will throw exception.

Comment: When I need to check for the if(st.isEmpty())?

I need to pop out two at once because of the algorithm ask to do so.

Comment: that's everytime when you going to pop. You need to understand the algo before start writing the code.

Comment: I just gave you answer why are you getting mentioned exception and how can you handle it.

Comment: I see. Then I need to do like this?
       `ch1 = st.pop();
       if(st.isEmpty()){
       }
       ch2 = st.pop();`

Is that how it works?

Comment: I would rather say there are lot of mess. You need to write your code again and handle this exception

Comment: If it were to handle the exception. Do I need to make a new class for handling the exception? Can't it do in the main class?

Comment: In one sentence. You need to check for empty stack whenever you are about to pop. You design your application accordingly